# Regarding Comma or Semi-Colon

Tags: punctuation

In this question: **"I am curious; what behavior are you referring to?"**.  Is it correct to use a semi-colon after curious, or to use a comma?  Such as, **"I am curious, what behavior are you referring to?"**

Comment: YACQ = yet another comma question; YAScQ = yet another semicolon question.

Comment: Close your eyes and say the sentence out loud. Does it sound like a full stop after "I am curious"? If so, use a semicolon. That's how easy it is.

Comment: Neither. Using a colon would make much more sense.

Comment: @Janus Yes – I'd use a dash here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution here is a colon. While "I am curious is an independent clause, it does not complete the thought being conveyed. A colon (which can be followed by either a dependent or an independent clause) is used not only to show a relationship between the two phrases, but also to indicate that the phrase to follow is a restatement, explanation or clarification of the first (or vice versa).

**Using a comma is *comma splicing***

**Using a semicolon only indicates a *contextual relationship***

**Using a colon in indicates a *co-reliance*.**

(The colon has other functions not as pertinent to this question).